# Rotation is slowly shrinking image

Tags: c, rotation, sdl

I am drawing a triangle using SDL. The following function is meant to take the coordinates of the triangle which are stored in the 'triCoords' array and rotate them by the specified angle around the center of the triangle which is stored in the 'triPos' array. However, while it seems to rotate correctly it is also shrinking the triangle over time

```
triCoords[0]=((triCoords[0] - triPos[0])*cos(angle) - (triCoords[1] - triPos[1])*sin(angle)) + triPos[0];
triCoords[1]=((triCoords[1] - triPos[1])*cos(angle) + (triCoords[0] - triPos[0])*sin(angle)) + triPos[1];
triCoords[2]=((triCoords[2] - triPos[0])*cos(angle) - (triCoords[3] - triPos[1])*sin(angle)) + triPos[0];
triCoords[3]=((triCoords[3] - triPos[1])*cos(angle) + (triCoords[2] - triPos[0])*sin(angle)) + triPos[1];
triCoords[4]=((triCoords[4] - triPos[0])*cos(angle) - (triCoords[5] - triPos[1])*sin(angle)) + triPos[0];
triCoords[5]=((triCoords[5] - triPos[1])*cos(angle) + (triCoords[4] - triPos[0])*sin(angle)) + triPos[1];
```

Comment: Always use the original (unmodified) image as the input argument for the rotate function.

Comment: Why does using the rotated coordinates cause it to shrink?

Answer (score 3):

Don't update the coordinates in-place, store the rotated coordinates in a separate array.

Comment: why would this top the image shrinking?

Comment: @CallumLukePerks: Because you aren't accumulating floating-point error by re-using the rotated positions.